# How can I mark dependencies for runtime only in a .nuspec file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I am using Visual Studio 2017, with the old style `.csproj` file format.

I am trying to build up a set of NuGet packages.

The initial layer (C NuGet package) exposes some piece of core functionality.The middle layer (B NuGet package) pulls in C and provides a set of methods. So, B has a dependency on C. The `.nuspec` for B lists C as a dependency.

Finally, I have an application (A Application) that pulls in the B NuGet package.  What I am trying to avoid is my application having references to C, but since C is marked as a dependency in B it gets added.

I do not want Visual Studio to add in a reference to C for application A.  I just need C artifacts at runtime so that B still works correctly.

A <-- B <-- C

If the C NuGet package has a `foo()` method, and I install B NuGet package into application A, application A can use the `C.foo()` method.  I only want application A to use exposed B methods.

How can I create the B `.nuspec` file to add the C NuGet dependency, but limit its usage to only the B NuGet package?  Is there some change I need to make to the C `.nuspec` file as well?

I have looked into include and exclude flags relating to dependencies, and could not find the combination to achieve what I want.

I tried using the newer `.csproj` format to let Visual Studio create the NuGet packages for me, but could not get that to work as I want.

If I remove the unwanted C references from application A, I lose those artifacts at runtime, so that did not work.

I see the `DevelopmentDependency` flag which indicates a package should be excluded from the output.  I am kind of looking for the notion of a `RuntimeDependency`, that is only included in the output.

`PrivateAssets` / `SuppressParent` does not sound right, since packages "should be consumed, but not flow to the next project".

Comment: If you have two nuget packages B and C. B depend on C, if you depend on B, it will automatically add reference to both B and C. So it's hard to avoid using C.foo() method in A application. Maybe you can contain C.dll in B package, and remove the dependency statement in .nuspec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a much different approach to handle this issue.  I am not sure I totally like it, but it serves my needs pretty well.

So, nothing changes with NuGet package C.  It gets built and packaged as before.

The goal of NuGet package B was to help facilitate using the logic in C in a service.  So, I turned B into a full blown service implementation that still references C.  The B NuGet package now consists of one DLL (which contains the service contract interface) that gets pulled into Application A, and uses an Install.ps1 to copy the necessary files into a separate directory.  There are no dependencies listed in NuGet B package.  So, the only reference in Application A, is that single DLL.

The good is that with everything in separate directories there will be no versioning issues between what B needs and what A needs.  Also, A does not get burdened with unnecessary dependencies from B.  It isn't the greatest, because some DLLs could be shared between the two.

Comment: Hi TPic, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, see [can I...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), it just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

> Finally, I have an application (A Application) that pulls in the B
>   NuGet package. What I am trying to avoid is my application having
>   references to C, but since C is marked as a dependency in B it gets
>   added.

It's expected behavior I think. If we have two nuget packages, A depend B with  `<dependency id="B" version="xxx" />` in `.nuspec` file, the application which consumes `Package B` will **automatically** install and reference `Package C`. And this point can be obviously proved when you use `packages.config` format to manage nuget packages.

So it's hard to get what you want in this way.

> How can I create the B .nuspec file to add the C NuGet dependency, but
>   limit its usage to only the B NuGet package?

When your Package B depend on Package C, if you consume `Package B`, it will reference `Package C` as well. So there's possibility to do what you want if the Package C is only used to provide C.dll as content during runtime. (It means if we reference Package C directly, it won't reference C.dll directly, only in this way it's possible for what you expected)

But if it's what you want. Why not contain the `C.dll` into `B.nupkg`. We only need to create B package which contains C.dll(not in lib folder when packing), then when we Consume B package in A, it will only reference B.dll. It works well during build time. And for the runtime, we just need to copy the `C.dll` into output folder. Then it works in both build time and runtime.

See [Content files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#example-contentfiles-section) element in `.nuspec` or [including targets in nuget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package), either of these two ways may help resolve your issuebut since I not familiar with Content files, so I use custom msbuild target to do this, and it works. Feel free to let me know if I misunderstand anything or there's better way :)

Comment: The issue with compiling C right into B in my scenario is that there are consumers of C that don't want the additional overhead that comes with pulling in B.  I have used .targets for run time only files, but could not see how to use .targets for another NuGet package dependency.  What I might end up doing is somehow combining B and C, and generate two different NuGet packages, one for a standalone C, and another for B that uses C as just a library and not a dependency.  I have other third party dependencies that follow a similar pattern, so still might have some unwanted references in the app

Comment: @TPic Hi, it seems you've found the workaround, maybe you can add it as answer to help other members. And according to your situation, why not create two packages! B package has both B.dll for build time and runtime and it also contains C.dll only for runtime. Then you have another C package for the consumers of C.